# How to restore uploaded backup in Drupal 7 (public files or entire website) correctly?

Tags: backups

When trying to restore public directory I see:

PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'temporary://cvetmagazin-2016-03-13T16-28-59.tar__0.gz' for key 'uri': INSERT INTO {file_managed} (uid, filename, uri, filemime, filesize, status, timestamp) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => cvetmagazin-2016-03-13T16-28-59.tar_.gz [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => temporary://cvetmagazin-2016-03-13T16-28-59.tar__0.gz [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => application/octet-stream [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 166375 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 1457901164 ) в функции drupal_write_record() (строка 7316 в файле /home/user/drupal_fish/apps/drupal/htdocs/includes/common.inc).

However, Drupal accepts database dump without errors. How to fix that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a concurrency issue when D7 makes a file object in db.
try to use this modules [Upload QC](https://www.drupal.org/project/upload_qc)
please let me know if it works with you.

also try to check the temp file name. and make sure tat the database is restored correctly.

Comment: finally, it accepts both public dir restore and database separately, however, nothing changes visually, though new files has appeared in folders